# I have two activity, when I click back button it has to go to previous activity,

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have two activity, cartActivity and paymentActivity.When I click back in payment activity it has to go back to the cartActivity but instead the app is closing completely. I don't get any error also.

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        this.finish()
    }
```

This is in payment activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While switching from CartActivity to PaymentActivity don't finish the CartActivity. So now when you press back you will switch to previous Activity.

Or simply write finish() instead of this.finish() in onBackPressed() Method like this.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    finish()
}
```

Hope this will solve.

Comment: I am not finnishing the cart activity, but still it isn't working

Comment: Can you share code segment where you have written the code for switching from CartActivity to PaymentActivity.

Comment: Got it.Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate from `CartActivity` to `paymentActivity`, make sure are not clearing the `backstack` using flags like these:

```
val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)

intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
```

These flags are responsible for clearing `backstack`, so in case you have used them, when you press back on `PaymentActivity` you will exit the app. This might be a reason for your problem, please provide complete code for more details.